# When using Webpack, which folder do I have my server statically serve?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Assuming I want to (my boss is making me) use webpack, and I have a file structure like:

[image: Folder structure, builds folder has bundle.js, src folder has index.html, index.js, and style.css]

Wherein `builds` is where webpack outputs the result of bundling/compiling the `src` folder, how do I then have `index.html` point to `bundle.js` if it is present on a server, i.e. which folder do I expose via `express.static()`? What is the correct "webpack" way to do this with i.e. a simple `webpack.config` like below? Am I missing something fundamental about how this works? Ideally I'd like to do something like the following in my `index.html`

```
<html>
<script src='bundle.js'></script> 
<!-- bundle.js spits a bunch of CSS into the html, dynamically builds elements, etc -->
</html>
```

Or is that not how things are done in webpack?

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path:     'builds',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, 
              loader: "style!css" 
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I have tried to figure this out via [the docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html) and [this oft-linked article](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a good practice to not expose any of your directory structure to end users as it creates a chance for web exploitation, nodejs with express has a mechanism to handle that. What you can do is expose this way your webpack

```
app.use('/buidscript', express.static(__dirname + '/builds/'));
```

Then, any browser requests from `/buidscript/bundle.js` will automatically be fetched from your builds directory.

```
<script src='/buidscript/bundle.js'></script>
```

Now you can gather your thoughts around this to make it in whatever way you would like.

For your ideal case which you are looking for

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/builds'));
```

Now you can use

```
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
```

as any request bundle.js will be searched in exposed static builds directory

Add it to package.json's script

```
“scripts”: {
 “start”: “webpack-dev-server --content-base build/ --inline --hot”,
 ...
 }
// Use it by running 
$ npm start
```

Now this will build your bundle.js before running index.html in development mode.

```
--content-base build/
```

will server the static files in your build folder. so then you can make use of bundle.js directly. It will look for any file changes and recompile bundle.js

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. If I expose `/builds`, then `bundle.js` can be accessed by clients. However, `index.html` cannot, and if I server `index.html`, it doesn't have access to `bundle.js`

Comment: If I go with your suggestion, I would deploy a `builds` folder with a copy of my `index.html` file in it, and then the deployment server would also add a `bundle.js` file in there.

Comment: I still didn't get why index.html won't be able to access bundle.js . when using webpack you have to differentiate between development and production environment. See the updated answer

Comment: Because `index.html` is inside `/src`, not inside `/build`

Comment: So a `GET` request for `root/index.html` will result in `cannot GET` because `index.html` won't be publicly accessible.

Comment: why can't you expose your public directory too. you can expose multiple directories one of them will be build and other will be your public. Then it won't say its not accessible

Comment: add this line to your app.js/server.js app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: did U get your answer?

Comment: I will check tomorrow morning, I'm afk